# How to return type table in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I create a type then used it to create a table such as:

```
CREATE TYPE PARTOK AS (col1 VARCHAR(58), col2 VARCHAR(58),  expiration VARCHAR(58), last_update BIGINT, date TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE PARTOK_JOB OF PARTOK;
```

Then I inserted a few lines:

```
INSERT INTO PARTOK_JOB VALUES ('one', 'test1','nothing',  0, null);
INSERT INTO PARTOK_JOB VALUES ('one', 'test2','nothing',  0, null);
INSERT INTO PARTOK_JOB VALUES ('one', 'test3','nothing',  0, null);
INSERT INTO PARTOK_JOB VALUES ('two', 'test3','nothing',  0, null);
```

I created a simple function to return a table of that type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_partok(
in_col1 VARCHAR(40)
)
RETURNS PARTOK_JOB

LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
SELECT * FROM partok_job WHERE col1 = in_col1 ;
$$
;
```

then used the following to call it:

```
SELECT * FROM get_partok('one');
```

The issue is that it returns a single line. How could I make it return all the related records?
Is there a way to do it using that type table or do I have to define each column of the return table?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html)

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning the result of the last query in the list. **In the simple (non-set) case, the first row of the last query's result will be returned**. (Bear in mind that “the first row” of a multirow result is not well-defined unless you use ORDER BY.) If the last query happens to return no rows at all, the null value will be returned.
>
> Alternatively, an SQL function can be declared to return a set (that is, multiple rows) by specifying the function's return type as **SETOF sometype**, or equivalently by declaring it as RETURNS TABLE(columns). In this case all rows of the last query's result are returned. Further details appear below.

You'll need to use `set_of`. just substitute in your code

```
RETURNS PARTOK_JOB
```

with

```
RETURNS setof PARTOK_JOB
```

The whole function definition should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_partok(
in_col1 VARCHAR(40)
)
RETURNS setof PARTOK_JOB

LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
SELECT * FROM partok_job WHERE col1 = in_col1 ;
$$
;
```

after making this change, when selecting

```sql
SELECT * FROM get_partok('one');
```

the output is

```
 col1 | col2  | expiration | last_update | date 
------+-------+------------+-------------+------
 one  | test1 | nothing    |           0 | 
 one  | test2 | nothing    |           0 | 
 one  | test3 | nothing    |           0 | 
(3 rows)
```